# Подскажите как сложить массивы, но что бы видеть только разницу?

Tags: php

```
        foreach ($result as $key => $res){
        foreach ($currentData as $key => $data)
        $res =  if(($res[key] == $data[key])Console::FG_YELLOW);{
                 echo 'все ок'
                }else{
             'разница'
    //пробовал функциб array_diff_uassoc, выбивает ощибку.
```

Comment: Вам нужна [Симметрическая разность](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C)? https://www.rosettacode.org/wiki/Symmetric_difference#PHP

Comment: по принципу array_diff_uassoc, в чем отличие отдного от другого

Comment: Смотрите документацию. https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.array-diff.php https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.array-diff-uassoc.php https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.array-diff-assoc.php и т.д.